# how to run symlink in laravel project inside add-on-domain?

Tags: laravel

I have an add-on-domain xyz.in inside public_html as 'public_html/xyz.in' and uploaded a laravel project inside xyz.in. However when I am uploading file using storage link the file is not getting saved inside public folder but the image is getting saved in storage folder. I am saving image in the following path

storage/app/public/images/

This is my htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is my web.php file inside routes.

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
        $run = Artisan::call('config:clear');
        $run = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
        $run = Artisan::call('config:cache');
        return 'FINISHED';  
    });
Artisan::call('storage:link');
Route::get('/', 'frontController@index')->name('homepage');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code I always use with symlink.

```
<?php
$target = '/home/public_html/xyz/storage/app/public';
$link = '/home/public_html/xyz/storage';

symlink($target, $link);

echo 'Symlink done!';
```

You can create a `symlink.php` file inside `public_html/xyz/public` and then go to the link.

Example:
http://www.xyx.com/symlink.php

** Don't forget to delete this file after you finish from linking the storage folder.

Comment: Showing 404 not found.

Comment: I can help you privately if you would like to.

Comment: Please help me.